# Error in adding radio buttons in a button group in Swing

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I want to covert my code in AWT to Swing in Java.

```
 ButtonGroup group1=new ButtonGroup();
JRadioButton radio1=new JRadioButton("Brute Force Technique",true);
JRadioButton radio2=new JRadioButton("Simulated Annealing Technique",false);
     //ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
     group1.add( radio1 );
group1.add(radio2);
```

But these lines are showing errors.

```
group1.add(radio1); 
and group1.add(radio2) ;
```

The error is:

```
error:package group1 does not exist <identifier> expected
```

I am working in Netbeans IDE 7.1.2. I am new to Java.  Can anyone please suggest what is the problem in my code?

My complete code which was written in AWT & I'm converting it to Swing is here:
[travellingsalesmanproblem.java](http://codes-at-igit.weebly.com/uploads/1/2/2/7/12272842/travellingsalesmanproblem.java).

Comment: 1) please stop to shout (broken CapsLock???), 2) you can debug your project by yourself, 3) for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @mKorbel I was not shouting sorry if you felt that. I just want to highlight it.

Comment: `javax.swing.JApplet` is "an extended version of `java.applet.Applet` that adds support for the JFC/Swing component architecture."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Create a method**... and inside that do this... or **Surround the "add" with {}**

eg:

```
     ButtonGroup group1=new ButtonGroup();
     JRadioButton radio1=new JRadioButton("Brute Force Technique",true);
     JRadioButton radio2=new JRadioButton("Simulated Annealing Technique",false);

    public void go()
{

     group1.add( radio1 );
     group1.add(radio2);

}
```

**OR**

```
     ButtonGroup group1=new ButtonGroup();
     JRadioButton radio1=new JRadioButton("Brute Force Technique",true);
     JRadioButton radio2=new JRadioButton("Simulated Annealing Technique",false);

     {

            group1.add( radio1 );
            group1.add(radio2);
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Operations like that should be invoked in block not in class field declaration section. Maybe move it to constructor or surround it by `{` `}` like

```
public class TravellingSalesmanProblem extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    ...

    ButtonGroup group1 = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton radio1Button=new JRadioButton("Brute Force Technique",true);
    JRadioButton radio2Button=new JRadioButton("Simulated Annealing Technique",false);
    {
        group1.add(radio1Button);
        group1.add(radio2Button);
    }
```

Comment: all the links that i have read does not included it in braces.http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/components/button.html#radiobutton ,so i thought it should work.

Comment: check [this](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/components/example-swing/RadioButtonDemo.java) it shows how to use code from your link. As you can see it is placed in constructor, not in field declaration section :)